# Is it possible to communicate between device via generated sound?

Tags: flutter, audio

There's a digital card app called "Bumpp" that enables app to app communications when both devices brought near (akin to NFC, but this does not need the device to be put back to back). One device continuously broadcasting the sound, and other device continuously listen for any sound emitted. The app claims to emit ultrasound audio, but I guess audio in any frequency is good enough for me.

Is it possible to achieve the same via Flutter?

- The sound emitted must be distinguishable from other audio, so my app doesn't accidentally pick up and translating sound from other audio picked up.
- I just need to transmit a simple thing, like an integer or something. No need to transfer things like file.
- Both app I presume will need some kind of agreed protocol, on what sound pattern to emit, and what sound pattern to listen.

Is there any good place where I can start reading about this?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find tools, software libraries or *other off-site resources* (such as a *good place* where you can start reading) are off-topic according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines.

Comment: @KenWhite Or perhaps you can recommend what query I should use to googling about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a Flutter-specific library to achieve this, but since Flutter apps can use any native API via MethodChannel, there is no way it can't be achieved because it is Flutter.

Here's the working solution I found: [qrtone](https://github.com/Ifsttar/qrtone)

Unfortunately, it seems to have dead before reaching version 1.0, but the minimum requirements are already in place.
It has a [Web demo](https://ifsttar.github.io/qrtone/) and an [Android demo](https://github.com/Ifsttar/qrtone-android). It also has a C port according to the readme (see bottom) which may be necessary for use on iOS.

As mentioned in the readme, the communication method itself is very similar to traditional communication methods such as dial-up connections or barcodes (not QR). If you want to implement from scratch, I suggest you start looking into that area.

Comment: Thank you, this is an interesting library to start investigating!